# Did Peirce's semiotics influence Saussure's own semiotic theory?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy

I am assuming that Saussure's semiotic theory came after Peirce's. Is there any indication that Saussure was aware of Peirce's theory? If not then was there any philosophical/scientific development(besides the work of Kant, Locke and earlier philosophers) during the early 19th century that may be considered a direct predecessor of semiotics?

Comment: Peirce left most of his works unpublished; thus, IMO there were no direct influence.

Comment: See [History of Semiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics#History_and_terminology): maybe John Locke.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I have skimmed over the text of the site of that link. Maybe one could look if Peirce published his semiotic theory(which seems very likely) and if any of the published papers by Peirce or those influenced by him could reach Saussure

Comment: Bits and pieces that appear in Peirce's works published in his lifetime do not amount to any "theory". The theory is scattered in letters and manuscripts that were not published until 1931 and after. Neither one of them referred to the other, and their dyadic and triadic conceptions are not particularly similar, see [The Semiotic Perspectives of Peirce and Saussure by Yakin and Totu](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277572736_The_Semiotic_Perspectives_of_Peirce_and_Saussure_A_Brief_Comparative_Study).

Comment: Definitely not. The question of Saussure's sources was much discussed a few decades ago; among the best studies is  Koerner, Ernst F. K.  *Ferdinand de Saussure, Origin and Development of his Linguistic Thought in Western Studies of Language*, reissued recently and largely viewable in googlebooks.